# Align two elements by content in StackView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have two UIView in StackView Horizontal. In UIView posted UILabel. I need the first one to be the priority. The main requirement is a complete lack of a fixed width in any UI.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Ua0.png)

Comment: Can you repeat the question? The first label have the priority on what? to show all the characters in the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [setContentCompressionResistancePriority(_:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622526-setcontentcompressionresistancep) higher for the required label and lower for the other one. Example:

```
textLabel1.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh, forAxis: .Horizontal)
textLabel2.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow, forAxis: .Horizontal)
```